# How to improve Python script performances when launched from systemd?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, debian, systemd, systemctl

I have a Raspberry Pi (there is a Debian-based distro) which needs to keep running a service based on a Python script.

What I have done so far has been to create the *.service* file added to the */lib/systemd/system/* folder, now it is run automatically at the system boot and it is able to be restarted if any crash occurs, furthermore, a little logging system has been added based on syslog.

The content of the *.service* file looks like this so far:

```
[Unit]
Description=My_Service
After=network.target network-online.target 
After=local-fs.target

[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=always
ExecStartPre=/bin/mkdir -p /home/user/log
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/python3 -u /home/user/my_service.py
SyslogIdentifier=My_Service
StandardOutput=syslog
StandardError=syslog

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Now I've noticed that the script is slighlty less performant than when it is run by terminal.

Because it is the only one script that the system should keep running, I was trying to set it with the highest priority but I am not sure how to do that.
So far I've added the following lines in the `[Service]` section but I'm not sure if it is ok or if it could be the best practice.

```
CPUSchedulingPolicy=rr
CPUSchedulingPriority=99
Nice=-20
```

The question is: How can I set the maximum priority and maximum usage of the system resources for such service in order to maximise its performances?

I'm also trying to disable other system services which are not useful for my embedded system, such as the *bluetooth.service*, could this kind of work be a good practice?

-- Edit --
No solutions found yet.

Comment: `CPUSchedulingPolicy=fifo` should be better than `rr`.

Comment: Tried with fifo but still no improvements. Let's assume that I have a while true loop which records from the microphone (passing through the FFmpeg libraries), each loop iteration when the script is launched manually takes between 18 to 21 ms, while when the script is launched from the systemd service, the iterations take up to 34 ms sometimes which is really bad form my real time purposes.

Comment: Perhaps `IOSchedulingClass=realtime` `IOSchedulingPriority=0` has an effect on reading the mike; I would have thought it was for disk i/o, but who knows. There is a whole mass of options under `man systemd.resource-control` which might apply, as systemd uses cgroups.

Comment: You can check, or change, the realltime scheduling of a process with `chrt`.

Answer (score -1):

To run python script as service I recommend to use Supervisor.

https://rcwd.dev/long-lived-python-scripts-with-supervisor.html

Comment: This does not solve the issue and only adds another layer of complexity to an embedded system. Moreover, supervisord will, just as well, have to be added as a service for a proper deployment.